Keycloak unable to start - Unable to start JGroups Channel
I deployed keycloak using help and attempting to start with preview features using kc.sh start --features=preview fails with error below
2024-11-25 20:27:22,079 INFO  [com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx] (main) ARJUNA032014: Stopping transaction recovery manager
2024-11-25 20:27:22,186 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (production) mode
2024-11-25 20:27:22,186 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start embedded or remote cache manager
2024-11-25 20:27:22,186 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: org.infinispan.manager.EmbeddedCacheManagerStartupException: Unable to start JGroups Channel
2024-11-25 20:27:22,187 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Unable to start JGroups Channel
2024-11-25 20:27:22,187 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Unable to start JGroups Channel
2024-11-25 20:27:22,187 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: No available port to bind to in range [7800 .. 7800]

I have tried to add these to my values.yaml and update the helm deployment however I get same error when I try to start KC
extraEnv:
  - name: KC_CACHE
    value: local
  - name: KC_CACHE_STACK
    value: local

